# Writing a conditional expression

Tags: syntax, conditional

I want to test a specific condition on `z1` and `z2` such that  if `z1` is greater than zero and `z2` is also greater than zero  then  it will print maximum otherwise it will print minimum.

This is what I have been trying to do without getting the result that I want, so would some one help me please.

```
z1={9,8,10,-2.4,0.5,3.4};
z2={-3,4,0.7,-4,-2,5.4};
v1= If[z5 >0 && z2>0,"Maximum"]
```

Comment: `v1 = Table[
  If[z1[[i]] > 0 && z2[[i]] > 0, "Maximum", "Minimum"], {i, 
   Length[z1]}]` or `v1 = If[z1[[#]] > 0 && z2[[#]] > 0, "Maximum", "Minimum"] & /@ 
  Range[Length[z1]]`

Comment: `Inner[ If[#1 > 0 && #2 > 0, "maximum", "minimum"] &, z1, z2, List]`

Comment: @ Feyre, corey979, m_goldberg, J. M.   I find you hold totally uncalled for.  You are making this forum a real pain in the butt and keeping people from making straight questions.  This is not the place to muscle your advance knowledge on WM. You were one time novice.  Put away your ON HOLD

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if I understood question OK, we'll see.

```
z1 = {9, 8, 10, -2.4, 0.5, 3.4};
z2 = {-3, 4, 0.7, -4, -2, 5.4};
If[#[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0, "Max", "Min", "equal"] & /@ Transpose@{z1, z2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This is another  option

```
z1 = {9, s, 10, -2.4, 0.5, 3.4, 0};
z2 = {-3, 4, 0.7, -4, -2, 3.4, 0};
If[#[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0, {Max[##], "Maximum"}, {Min[##], "Minimum"}, {##, 
     "Undetermined"}] & /@ Transpose@{z1, z2} // TableForm
```

Comment: My answer was inspired by Nasser. Please vote him up.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
z1={9,8,10,-2.4,0.5,3.4};
z2={-3,4,0.7,-4,-2,5.4};

{Min,Max}[[1 + UnitStep[z1] UnitStep[z2]]]
```

> {Min,Max,Max,Min,Min,Max}